# Angular Reactive forms : how to get just changed values

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

Im building a reactive forms using angular 6, this form contain 3 attributes (name,age,phone) and i would to get just the changed values not all form values.

```
this.refClientForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: [],
  phone: [],
  age: []
});
```

for the form listener :

```
 this.refClientForm.valueChanges.subscribe(values => console.log(values))
```

but i got always all form values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 getting only the dirty values in a controlgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342444/angular-2-getting-only-the-dirty-values-in-a-controlgroup)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can check all controls for dirty-flag. See https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

```
getDirtyValues(form: any) {
        let dirtyValues = {};

        Object.keys(form.controls)
            .forEach(key => {
                let currentControl = form.controls[key];

                if (currentControl.dirty) {
                    if (currentControl.controls)
                        dirtyValues[key] = this.getDirtyValues(currentControl);
                    else
                        dirtyValues[key] = currentControl.value;
                }
            });

        return dirtyValues;
}
```

Comment: controls object  is not a array

Comment: Yeah you are right. I updated the post. But the idea is the same. Of course you could also loop over the controls obejcts via `for in` or something like then you also get the name.

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342444/angular-2-getting-only-the-dirty-values-in-a-controlgroup

Comment: Just because a control is dirty it doesn't mean that its value is different than the initial. The control becomes dirty the minute a user edits its value, but it doesn't care if the new value is the same as before.

Answer (score 7):

Better answer found here:

[Angular 2 Reactive Forms only get the value from the changed control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296549/angular-2-reactive-forms-only-get-the-value-from-the-changed-control)

```
this.imagSub = this.imagingForm.valueChanges.pipe(
    pairwise(),
    map(([oldState, newState]) => {
      let changes = {};
      for (const key in newState) {
        if (oldState[key] !== newState[key] && 
            oldState[key] !== undefined) {
          changes[key] = newState[key];
        }
      }
      return changes;
    }),
    filter(changes => Object.keys(changes).length !== 0 && !this.imagingForm.invalid)
  ).subscribe(
    value => {
      console.log("Form has changed:", value);
    }
  );
```

Comment: This was what I needed, as I just want the "latest" changed value instead of "all" changed values. I also like the rxJs utilities used for this.

Comment: With this answer, the code inside subscribe is not executed for the the very first value change

Comment: This code compares changes to the previous form value, not the initial one. The `pairwise` operator will keep the current and previous value, but the `valuechanges` event will fire every time any input changes, so the previous value can already be different than the initial.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to check if any control is dirty in the reactive form.

```
getUpdatedValues() {
 const updatedFormValues = {};
 this.form['_forEachChild']((control, name) => {
  if (control.dirty) {
      this.updatedFormValues[name] = control.value;
  }
});
console.log(this.updatedFormValues);
```

Comment: Not good practice to use `_forEachChild`, the other answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

use pairwise() operator with startWith(this.refClientForm.value) operator
then form valueChanges will emit on first try

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).