# Angular forms: value changes for each individual control

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'd like to listen to valuechanges of my form, but not for the entire form but only for the formcontrol that was changed.

If for example my form looks like this.

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
  firstName: [''],
  lastName: [''],
  ... // other stuff.
});
```

If I then subscribe to valuechanges

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Then filling in a firstname in the form would result in a printout of the entire form value object.

> {firstName: 'input', lastName: '', ...}

But what I want to know is which form control (in this case the `firstName`) was altered without subscribing to each individual form control. Such that my desired output is only

> {firstName: 'input'}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Reactive Forms only get the value from the changed control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296549/angular-2-reactive-forms-only-get-the-value-from-the-changed-control)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, multiple `AbstractControl`s(e.g `FormControl,` `FormGroup`, `FormArray`) are stored internally as a tree.

```
// FG - FormGroup
// FA - FormArray
// FC - FormControl

    FG
  /   \
FC    FG
    /    \
  FC     FA
        / | \
      FC FC FC
```

*The above snippet is excerpted from [*A thorough exploration of Angular Forms*](https://indepth.dev/posts/1143/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms).*

Because of that reason, a `FormGroup.valueChanges` emits when a `FormGroup` child's `valueChanges` emits:

```js
updateValueAndValidity (/* ... */) {
  /* ... */

  if (opts.emitEvent !== false) {
    (this.valueChanges as EventEmitter<any>).emit(this.value);
    (this.statusChanges as EventEmitter<string>).emit(this.status);
  }
  
  if (this._parent && !opts.onlySelf) {
    this._parent.updateValueAndValidity(opts);
  }
  
  /* ... */
}
```

In the [above snippet](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L729), if we were to consider your example, `_parent` could refer to the `this.form` `FormGroup` instance when the `firstName` `FormControl` receives some input.

---

So, a way to achieve what you're looking for would be this:

```js
merge(
  ...Object.keys(this.form.controls).map(
    k => this.form.controls[k].valueChanges.pipe(
      // Getting a decent format: `{ formControlName: formControlValue }`
      map(v => ({ [k]: v })),
    )
  )
).subscribe(console.log)
```

The `FormGroup.controls` has [this signature](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1425):

```js
public controls: {[key: string]: AbstractControl},
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
  this.form.get("firstName").valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue => {
      console.log(selectedValue)     
    })
```

Comment: No, I explicitly said that I did not want to subscribe to each individual form control. In this generic example, there are only 2 hardcoded controls but in my real case scenario there are many more controls which names are not known beforehand but can be dynamic.

Comment: Yes. Got your point . Please follow this link -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729248/how-to-get-formcontrolname-of-the-field-which-value-changed-in-angular-reactive

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to listen form control changes:

custom validation method:

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
  firstName: ['', [this.fieldValidator]],
  lastName: [''],
  ... // other stuff.
});

fieldValidator(control: FormControl) {
     // control?.value available here
     // return null
}
```

or
cross-validation method:

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
  firstName: [''],
  lastName: [''],
  ... // other stuff.
}, { validators: exampleValidator});

export const exampleValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const firstName = control.get('firstName');
  // firstName?.value available here, etc
  // return condition ? null : { inValid: true};
};
```